# HTML: Autoscroll merged table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, html-table

I got a table were the first row is merged and an image is displayed:

[image]

How can I get the image to autoscroll when the page is scrolled down, so that the image is always in the middle of the visible(!) table?

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="10">Image</th>
    <th>c</th>
    <th>c</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in the middle of the visible(!) table"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jquery function **scrollTop()** and handling the **on scroll** event See the [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36rvnjsk/3/) :

```
$(function($) {
    var image = $('.follow-scroll');
    var originalPosition = image.offset().top;

    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topSpace = 15;

    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    image.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        image.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalPosition ? 0: scrollTop - originalPosition + topSpace
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: Thanks that works, but there is one Problem, the image "overscrolls" the table, so the image is outside the table if you scroll further down.Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Thank you so much!! The "-85" in the limit var is the size of the image + margin ?